# How to get the text value of parent <a> tag element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a click function of Jquery to get the text value of submenus(Mobiles,Camera). I also want to get the text vale of parent element of these items(Electronics). How can I achieve this using JQuery

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu" id="subCategory">
  <a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Electronics</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="elecItems">
    <li><a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
    <li><a  class="insideElement" href="#">Cameras</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Pendrives</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Televisions</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

When I click on Mobile, I want to the text Value as Electronics from the parent  tag element.

**Script to get the text value of sub menu:**

```
$('#subCategory li').on('click', function(){
   var selectedItem=$(this).text(); 
});
```

Similar to the above script can I get the value of parent element as Electronics

Comment: `$.(this).closest('ul').prev('a').text();`

Comment: @Teemu: Thank you. Allergy eyes this morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to getting parent `a` text.

JAVASCRIPT-

```
var parentElmnt = $(this).closest('#subCategory').find('a:eq(0)').text();
```

Comment: My pleasure. @NikhilBharadwaj

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).closest('ul').siblings('a').text();` for this. Check updated snippet below

```js
$('#subCategory li').on('click', function(){
   var selectedItem=$(this).closest('ul').siblings('a').text(); 
   console.log(selectedItem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown-submenu" id="subCategory">
  <a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Electronics</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="elecItems">
    <li><a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
    <li><a  class="insideElement" href="#">Cameras</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Pendrives</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Televisions</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#subCategory li').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).find('a').text());
  console.log($(this).parents(".dropdown-menu").siblings("a").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown-submenu" id="subCategory">
  <a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Electronics</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="elecItems">
    <li><a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Cameras</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Pendrives</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Televisions</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

```
$('#subCategory li a').on('click', function(){
  var selectedItem=$(this).text(); 
});
```

or

```
$('#subCategory li').on('click', function(){
  var selectedItem=$(this).find('.insideElement').text(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a function to every li inside `#subcategory`and find the element you are looking for from them.

```
$('#subCategory li').click(function() 
    var a = $(this).parent().prev();
    alert($(a).html()); 

});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
$.(this).closest('ul').prev('a').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/yuh4bq33/2/

```js
$('#subCategory li').on('click', function(){
   console.log("Parent:" + $(this).parent().prev().text()); 
   console.log("Sub Menu:" + $(this).find('a').text()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown-submenu" id="subCategory">
  <a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Electronics</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="elecItems">
    <li><a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
    <li><a  class="insideElement" href="#">Cameras</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Pendrives</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Televisions</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following jquery get text of category and list item

```
 $('#subCategory ul li').click(function(){
    var selectedItem=$(this).find("a").html();  // Selected list item
    var selectedItem2=$(this).closest("#subCategory").find("a").first().html();  // Electronics
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#subCategory li').on('click', function(){
   var selectedItem=$(this).text(); 
   var parent = $('#subCategory').children('a').text();
   $(this).text(parent); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. You need to use `parents()`, `siblings()` and `find()`. Also, make sure to use the class name to while doing `find()` else, it make fetch all the tags:

```js
$('#subCategory li').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).parents(".dropdown-menu").siblings("a.insideElement").text() + ' => ' + $(this).find('a.insideElement').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown-submenu" id="subCategory">
  <a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Electronics</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="elecItems">
    <li><a class="insideElement" tabindex="-1" href="#">Mobiles</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Cameras</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Laptop</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Pendrives</a></li>
    <li><a class="insideElement" href="#">Televisions</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```